# Why FacesServlet cannot have a url-pattern of /*.?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, url-pattern, servlet-mapping

This is my web.xml :

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I navigate to:

```
http://localhost:8080/LearningRoot/index.xhtml
```

I can see the page just fine, however when I navigate to:

```
http://localhost:8080/LearningRoot/
```

I get the error:

> An Error Occurred:
>
> **The FacesServlet cannot have a url-pattern of /*. Please define a different url-pattern.**

But why?

And this is my welcome file:

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: @KeremBaydoğan did you try it in a real Java web application?

Comment: nope :) That was just a guess :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because that would mean **Everything** that ever hits that context-root will be handled by FacesServlet, a requirement that FacesServlet already knows it couldn't possibly fulfill (It obviously doesn't make sense).

To achieve the mapping you intend, use a `.xhtml` mapping on FaceServlet

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: @KorayTugay `/` will let it default to the `index` file per standard webapp processing. `/*` is an ambiguous reference